# How do I create a function to accept [[customerID]] and return CustName Please look at details

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been asked to created a Function to accept CustomerID and return CustomerName for the CustomerID, I m a new Student/Developer Please if the question is not clear let me know so i can add more details about it, but that is what I was exactly asked.

Comment: I guess you'd start by reviewing your learning materials for SQL.  Looking at the database schema would be a good step, too.

Comment: This link might help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Thank you David. I mostly use my learning materials and Microsoft web, but sometime I come to the point where I can't get exactly what i am looking for so I stop by here to ask for help and direction from great developers like yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) in SQL are of three types.ignoring rest CLR functions ...

```
create table test
(
id int,
name varchar(4)
)

insert into test
select 1,'abc'
union all
select 2,'cde'
```

1.**Scalar function** takes one value and return one value

now for the above table ,you can create scalar function like below

```
create function dbo.test
(
@id int
)
returns varchar(4)
as
begin
declare @name varchar(4)
select @name=name from test where id =@id
 return @name
End
```

**You invoke it like:**

```
select  dbo.test(1)
```

2.**Inline table valued functions**:takes a single input same like scalar functions and returns table

```
create function dbo.test
(
@id int
)
as 
returns TABLE
(
select * from test where id=@id)
```

**You invoke it like:**

select * from dbo.test(1)

3.**Multi table valued function**:

```
create function dbo.test
(
@id int
)
returns 
@test table
(
id int,
name varchar(4)
)
as
begin

insert into @test
select * from test where id =@id

return

end
```

You invoke it like:
select * from dbo.test(1)

Take any one of Itzik Ben Gan books and start learning SQL the way it should be learned